# Rails dynamic nested attribute form not validating on update

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a nested attribute form that I'm having trouble getting to validate after I've removed all the related fields on edit. The form represents a `has_many :through` many to many relationship. The form works well on create.  If I haven't added any nested fields and hit submit, the validations work. However when I edit an existing record and remove all the nested fields then submit, the validations aren't triggering and all the child attributes are deleted from the database.

I need to understand what's going amuck. I also need a solution to the problem.

Here's my models:

expense.rb

```
class Expense < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :payee
  monetize :amount_cents
  has_many :expense_expense_categories, inverse_of: :expense
  has_many :expense_categories, through: :expense_expense_categories, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :expense_expense_categories,:allow_destroy => true

  validates_associated :expense_expense_categories
  validates :date, presence: true
  validates_numericality_of :amount, presence: true, greater_than: 0
  validates :expense_expense_category_ids, presence: true
  validates_presence_of :payee_id
end
```

expense_expense_category.rb

```
class ExpenseExpenseCategory < ApplicationRecord
  monetize :amount_cents
  belongs_to :expense, inverse_of: :expense_expense_categories
  belongs_to :expense_category, inverse_of: :expense_expense_categories

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :expense_category

  validates_numericality_of :amount, presence: true, greater_than: 0
end
```

expense_category.rb

```
class ExpenseCategory < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :expense_expense_categories,inverse_of: :expense_category
  has_many :expenses, through: :expense_expense_categories

  validates_presence_of :category
end
```

I'm going to omit most of the `Expense` form showing only the entry point for the nested attributes

_form.html.erb

```
<%= f.fields_for :expense_expense_categories do |builders| %>
  <%= render 'expense_expense_category_fields', :f => builders %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to_add_fields "Add Category", f, :expense_expense_categories %>
```

expense_expense_category_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="expense_categories_fields">
  <div class="ui form segment">
    <div class="ui grid">
      <div class="sixteen wide column">
        <%= link_to '<i class="link red large remove icon"></i>'.html_safe, "#", :class => "remove_expense_expense_categories", style:"float:right" %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>

        <div class="field">
          <%=f.label :amount %>
          <%= f.text_field :amount %>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
          <%=f.label :category%>
          <%= f.select :expense_category_id, ExpenseCategory.all.collect { |p| [p.category, p.id] },{prompt: "Choose Category"} %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

edit.js.coffee (where I think the problem is)

```
$('#expense_form').html("<%= escape_javascript(render "form") %>")

$('form').on 'click', '.add_fields', (event) ->
  time = new Date().getTime()
  regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
  $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
  event.preventDefault()

$('form').on 'click', '.remove_expense_expense_categories', (event) ->
  $(this).next('input[type=hidden]').val(true)
  $(this).closest('.expense_categories_fields').hide()
  event.preventDefault()
```

Hiding the expense category fields does not remove them from params therefore still submitted with the form. But.. since the _destroy hidden field is set to true, the record gets deleted.  I've tried disabling the fields preventing them from being submitted with the form, but that didn't seem to trigger any validation errors either.

here's what that looked like:

```
$(this).siblings("div.field").find('input').attr('disabled', true)
$(this).siblings("div.field").find('select').attr('disabled',true)
$(this).closest('.expense_categories_fields').hide()
```

So i'm stuck with a broken form

Comment: I didn't see it - do you have an id attribute on the nested elements in the form?

Comment: yes, but since they are dynamically created, you can't determine what they are.  That's why I'm forced to use siblings.find

Comment: For existing existing expense categories, you'll need a hidden field to store the id.  What params to you permit in the controller?

Comment: Yes the hidden field is there with the id of the expense record.  I am permitting all attributes for both relationships.

Comment: My issue is not creating the items, It's when editing the items and removing all the nested fields.  When I remove them all and hit update, it should go through validations again. Instead it deletes them breaking the "Expense must have at least one category" validation.

Comment: I've never seen a validates on a has many `validates :expense_expense_category_ids, presence: true`.  Would this always be true?  (even with an empty array)

Comment: Maybe Instead of presence: true I could test for blankness?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113468/discussion-between-ctilley79-and-swards).